# Model not updating after jquery ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm working on a application which should return multiple list based on selected values.

When a organisation is selected a few queries will run to populate a selectlist.
These queries only return data relevant for the selected organisation.

After that there is a dropdownlist to select which selectlist should be displayed. This will populate another dropdownlist with the data returned from the query.

On the initial load it is loaded correctly for the first organisation. However when another organisation is selected, an ajax post will call a method. this will run the queries succesfully and set the properties to the returned lists. however the problem is that the razor page still uses the data from the initial load.

this results in the fact that whatever organisation i will select, it will use the data from the queries for the first organisation on the razor page.

below the ajax call

```
         $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Aanleveringen/Create?handler=Filter",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                dataType: "json",
                data: { organisatieId: $('#ddlOrganisatie option:selected').val() },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Error try again");
                }
            });
```

and the method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OnPostFilter(int organisatieId)
    {
        Filter filter = new Filter();
        Organisatie organisatie = _context.Organisatie.Distinct().Where(x => x.Id == organisatieId).First();         
        FilterWaardeGemeente = filter.GetFilterGemeente(organisatie);
        FilterWaardeDienst = filter.GetFilterDienst(organisatie);
        FilterWaardeClient = filter.GetFilterClient(organisatie);
        return new JsonResult("Gelukt");
    }
```

looking for any suggestion to have the razor page model update with the most recent c# pagemodel.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show us your Razor page code to see how do you use viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your model isn't going to do anything, as the Razor page is not being re-rendered. Since you're making the request via AJAX, you need to return your select list items from that action, and then use JavaScript to update the select list options manually in the DOM.